# Handle formatting of longtext value for entity wrapper

Tags: 7, entities

So I have a working setup where some code pulls in the latest Wikipedia extract of a page.  I then use Entities to handle a node creation, adding the contents of the extract to the longtext value of the generic body field:

```
$body = array();
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles='.urlencode($item['name']);
$result = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($result){
  // Oh yes!
  $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
  foreach ($decoded['query']['pages'] as $page){
    if (array_key_exists('extract', $page)){
      $body[] = t($page['extract']);
    }
  }
} else {
  // Boo, nothing found.
}

// Doesn't exist, we have to make it first. (Using Entities)
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'article', 'uid' => 1));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node); // $node->nid is probably better here
$entity->title->set($item['name']);
if ($body){
  $entity->body->set(array('value' => $body[0]));
}
$entity->save();
// Woo got our nid!
$nid = $entity->getIdentifier();
```

The problem is, I can't seem to control the output of the body at all.  It renders surrounded with paragraph tags, using html line breaks for each paragraph.  I want to surround each paragraph with paragraph tags.  I've tried using preg_match to catch newlines (\r\n) but anything I replace it with just gets rendered exactly - making paragraph tags show up in the extract text when viewing the node.

What's the best method of doing some formatting to the extract?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify a format for your text value:

```
$entity->body->set(array('value' => $body[0], 'format' => 'full_html'));
```