# Get text_long field value with EntityMetadataWrapper

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to get data from a `text_long` type field using `EntityMetadataWrapper`, and from what I'm seeing on the interwebs, I should be using something like this:

```
$wrapper->{$field}->value();
```

or

```
$wrapper->{$field}->value->value();
```

However, if I use the first one, I get an array with `format` and `value` keys, but if I try the latter, I get an Call to a member function value() on null` error.

Do I have to use `$wrapper->{$field}->value();` and manually get the `value` from the array? Or is there a more direct method? I've looked through the class, I don't see another method that gets the `value` data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the long text field is an array in the entity Metadata wrapper (due to fact that long text fields can have an input format applied to them),  you should decode the text.

1. [See the Drupal.org entity Metadata documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers#rendering-fields-from-a-wrapper) and search for the example
   $wrapper->body->value->value(array('decode' => TRUE));
2. Also, check out [this similar post about handling the formatting of long text fields when extracting with entity Metadata wrappers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191889/79832)